# strtotime() not converting correctly in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing an issue in strtotime() in wordpress, that it is subtracting the hours according to my configured local timezone.

For example i tried `strtotime("2021-11-16 00:00:00")` on online php compiler it shows...

> 1637020800

but when i run the same on my wordpress site, `var_dump(strtotime("2021-11-16 00:00:00"));` it shows:

> 1637002800

which is wrong it is subtracting 5 hours as i set GMT+5 in my general settings.

I tried **current_time('timestamp')** but it won't help

Please can anyone help?

Comment: If I read the manual carefully that doesn't seem possible. You have an absolute date and time. `strtotime()` should parse that into the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware is it possible January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC not set as base date and time and it can be check some how?

Comment: i run simply this `var_dump(strtotime("2021-11-16 00:00:00"));` but it shows wrong which is, 1637002800

Comment: Of course that is possible, but if I go by what is written in the manual it shouldn't work like that. Seems like the timezone has an effect. I guess it could first translate your absolute time, in your timezone, to UTC and then count the seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware but that is happening :-(

Comment: Yes, it is using the timezone, because it says in the manual for `strtotime()`: _"Every call to a date/time function will generate a E_WARNING if the time zone is not valid."_. It wouldn't say that if it didn't use a timezone.

Comment: In a comment, in the manual, it says: _"strtotime() will convert a string WITHOUT a timezone indication as if the string is a time in the default timezone. See:  date_default_timezone_set()"_

Comment: Are you using a hardcoded string in both cases, or in one case are you getting data from the database

Comment: @KIKOSoftware let me try mate, i am trying in another application also

Comment: @KIKOSoftware
it shows, bool(false) but amazingly same thing in other installation of wordpress shows correct in same file.

Comment: The trick here is that `2021-11-16 00:00:00"` is still not an absolute date/time because it is missing a timezone. Only something like `2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00` is absolute. The `+02:00` at the end is the timezone. Therefore your date is taken relative to the timezone you set.

Comment: i found the problem in worpress, so basically in time zone if you select city,country it shows you this problem. While if you select like GMT +5 etc it will show correct.

Comment: Thank you sir, @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Thank you mate @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem in wordpress version 5.4.2, so basically in time zone if you select city,country it shows you this problem.
While if you select like GMT +5 etc it will show correct.

So i change **Karachi** to **GMT+5** which make it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
function wp_strtotime($str) {
    return strtotime( wp_date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $str ) ) );
}
```

Comment: what you say about **date_i18n()** i found it useful. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/